# Is it possible to open popup window in button click event without using jquery in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I want to open popup window in button click event without using j-query in asp.net C#.
This is simple task i am familiar with Asp.Net MVC. But i am not familiar in Asp.Net so only i am struggling for this simple task.

Please any one tell me how to open popup window by button click event without using jquery in asp.net C#.

My web form

## SpecilalityMaster.Aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="specialitymaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="popupwindow.admin.specialitymaster" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <form id="frmPopupExample" runat="server">

<asp:Button ID="btnOpenPopupWindow" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Open Popup Window" OnClick="btnOpenPopupWindow_Click" 
             />
 </form>

<div class="popup">
     <asp:TextBox ID="_lname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="save" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
             />
    </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

## specialitymaster.aspx.cs

```
public partial class specialitymaster : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnOpenPopupWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

i just tried simply. i designed one button and one popup window.if i click open popup window in button click event i need to open popup window. i donno it is possible or not.i created button click event in CS page but i donno how to call that popup window name in button click event .

example

[Desirable result: Please see image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZXW1.png)

Comment: do you use bootstap?

Comment: in asp.net how to use bootstrap

Comment: @VladimirChikrizov What does bootstrap have to do with opening a new window? Is plain javascript ok?

Comment: @VladimirChikrizov is it possible to use bootstrap in asp.net then what is the need of bootsrap for my question

Comment: just use javascript, it's very straight forward

Comment: my my concern requirement is without using jquery

Comment: @Swetha, Sorry, to accomplish what you have on your image, you'll need drop idea about server-side processing. You'll need to use bootstrap - this is the easiest and STANDARD way to have overlay window. You can google keywords "bootstrap overlay" and you will see gazillion of examples

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need a popup, you just trying to activate some div on your page. You will need to make this div  server side

```
<div class="popup" runat="server" style="display:none" id="divPop">
 <asp:TextBox ID="_lname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="save" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
         />
</div>
```

and then in your server side click

```
protected void btnOpenPopupWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  divPop.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block);
}
```

this will make your div visible

> EDIT
>   better solution in your case would be using asp panel instead of div.

```
<asp:panel id="divPop" visible="false" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="_lname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

      <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="save" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
     />
</asp:panel>
```

and then you will be able to manipulate visibility in your server side code very easy

```
protected void btnOpenPopupWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  divPop.Visible=true;
}
```

Comment: yuri i have attached one eg image in question please see that like that only i want to achieve

Comment: how to open as popup which is mention same as like in that image .Visible is just show and hide that div i need open as popup

Comment: Your panel lacks the `runat="server"` attribute.

Comment: i added  that runat="server". now what i need is how to open as POPUP.Visible just hide and show div in same parent window . i need to open as popup window same as like mention in that image

Answer (score 0):

you are using server side control in your code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenPopupWindow" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Open Popup Window" OnClick="btnOpenPopupWindow_Click" 
         />
```

click of this button will trigger immediate post to the server and server (your ASP.NET application) will handle the event. The only way you will be able to open a popup from the server if you will register script to do this. Your CLick should look something like

```
 protected void btnOpenPopupWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
    "yourWindowName", 
     String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", yourURL));
}
```

Comment: in your URL place what ihave to give yuri

Comment: for the testing purpose put https://stackoverflow.com
and later on replace with the url that you are really want to open

Comment: yuri i want to open popup window in same window not as separate window. eg in my code i mention <div class="popup"> in button click event i open this div as popup window

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
var DefineWindowSize= "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var URL = "https://www.google.com";
var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", DefineWindowSize);
```

Create a function and add it inside the function.